# SQL Server: pass next value of sequence to procedure

Tags: sql-server, call, sequence, procedure

I'm new to Microsoft SQL Server. I have to call an existing procedure and I want to pass the next value of an sequence.

Here a rough overview of my objects and the way I want to pass the values:

I've created an sequence, like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySeq START WITH 10000 CACHE 50;
```

Also, I created a procedure like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_MY_PROCEDURE
     (@V_TECHNICAL_ID BIGINT, @V_VALUE VARCHAR(254))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable (key, value) 
    VALUES (@v_technical_id, @v_value);
END@
```

Now, I would like to call the procedure mentioned above the following way:

```
EXEC P_MY_PROCEDURE NEXT VALUE FOR mySeq, 'Some Value';
```

While using the previous line, I get the following error:

> [Error Code: 102, SQL State: S0001]  Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT

What is wrong? With other RDBMS (like Oracle, DB2), the way execution the procedure works without any problems

Answer (score 3):

Stored procedures can only be called with literal values or variables/parameters. No functions (user defined or otherwise), or other SQL constructs. So you have to assign `next value for mySeq` to something first. Another example of this same phenomenon is if you were to try to pass `getdate()` into a procedure; it won't let you.

Try this:

```
declare @seqval int = next value for myseq

exec P_MY_PROCEDURE @seqval, 'some value'
```